# Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd

Tags: java, spring

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecNwO.png)

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:428)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    ... 22 more
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the contents of the file in your screenshot as text, rather than as an image.  For one thing, those who use screenreaders will be unable to help you.  For another thing, search engines can't search the text of your screenshot, but they could search it if you included it in your question as text, and this might help someone else who has the same issue as you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  See [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Also, your question doesn't ask a question. Currently, you're just documenting the fact that you are getting an error. What do you want to know? Please ask explicitly, so as to align your post with the site's format.